# setPivotY() behave strange on Android

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView which I want it to enlarge once the app is launched

So, firstly I did this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.screenshot198);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

    layout.addView(imageView);

    imageView.setPivotX(1.0f);
    imageView.setScaleX(1.5f);
    imageView.setScaleY(1.5f);
}
```

It works great!

[image]

Then I try to set it at bottom by adjusting the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.screenshot198);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

    layout.addView(imageView);

    imageView.setPivotX(1.0f);
    imageView.setPivotY(1.0f);
    imageView.setScaleX(1.5f);
    imageView.setScaleY(1.5f);
}
```

Hey! What's going on with my tree!?

[image]

The only difference between these two paragraphs of code is that, I've added [params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);] in order to put image at bottom, and added [setPivotY(1.0f);] so the image should scale upward from bottom.

But it seems the [setPivotY(1.0f);] doesn't work properly. Anything I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: afair setpivotY accepts a pixel value as parameter... try setPivotY(imageView.getHeight())

Answer (score 0):

Comment by @rupps surprisingly helped me. Changing to `setPivotY(view.getHeight())` fixed my case.

When using `setPivotY(view.getBottom())` I was getting an unexpected offset/margin when using `setScaleY()`.